# checkbox not getting unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, checkbox

i am having 4 checkboxes and with the help of ajax am toggling between inserting data on checked and deleting it on unchecked. I am able to insert data successfully but the problem lies in the first checkbox as am unable to uncheck it once it gets checked

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<input id="prof" type="checkbox" onclick="insdel('Cricket')" value="Cricket" /><span>Cricket</span>
<input id="prof" type="checkbox" onclick="insdel('Football')" value="Football" /><span>Football</span>
<input id="prof" type="checkbox" onclick="insdel('Hockey')" value="Hockey" /><span>Hockey</span>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is my javascript

```
function insdel(answer) {
if(document.getElementById("prof").checked = true){
document.forms["t"]["ttq"].value= answer;
if((document.forms["t"]["ttq"].value)!=""){
var xmlhttp;    
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","pop.php?q="+answer,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}

}
else{
document.forms["t"]["ttq"].value= answer;
if((document.forms["t"]["ttq"].value)!=""){
var xmlhttp;    
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","del.php?q="+answer,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}

}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: invalid html, duplicate ids `id="prof"`

Comment: if i change that then i have to use many ajax code.. please if you could guide me on that. as my checkbox list is very long

Comment: try to use name in attribute instead of the id to group a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample code to make it clear

```js
var insdel = function(chk) {
  console.log(chk.value, chk.checked, chk.id);
  if (chk.checked) {
    console.log('insert ', chk.value);
    //do the rest
  } else {
    console.log('delete ', chk.value);
    //do the rest
  }
  //do the rest
};
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset><!-- updated ids, also the onclick parameter -->
    <input id="prof1" type="checkbox" onclick="insdel(this)" value="Cricket" /><span>Cricket</span>
    <input id="prof2" type="checkbox" onclick="insdel(this)" value="Football" /><span>Football</span>
    <input id="prof3" type="checkbox" onclick="insdel(this)" value="Hockey" /><span>Hockey</span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```